# Rails "as_json" method returning invalid json?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to have a iOS application read json generated by a rails server.  For now, I am just having it be a text file, but the eventual goal is for it to be retrieved via a route.

The iOS application is throwing errors trying to read (which was generated with as_json):

```
{"created_at"=>Fri, 16 Aug 2013 13:21:07 UTC +00:00, "gender"=>"M", "id"=>1, "location_id"=>1, "max_hit_points"=>nil, "my_name"=>"Jim Bob", "npc_type_id"=>nil, "universe_id"=>1, "updated_at"=>Fri, 16 Aug 2013 13:21:07 UTC +00:00}
```

when I give that to a json validator (http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)

I get several errors about nearly everything, especially how it has "=>" rather than a colon.

Am I doing something completely weird?  Why does rails seem to not generate valid json?  Are there somehow multiple types of valid json (arrows vs colons?)  How can I make it generate json that the iOS app (or that validator) likes?

Comment: This looks like a hash, not json. how did you get it to do this? In a rails controller? Or puts? Or writing to a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`as_json` is used to prepare a hash suitable for json rendering. ([see doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json))

You need to call `to_json` to get the real json string.

For example :

```
your_object.as_json.to_json
```

More info on the difference and the implications [can be found here](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/)

Comment: Yup, I just realized that myself. Stack Overflow will let me choose your answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Gah, it was my own stupid fault.  "as_json" turns something into a literal ruby json object (which is a hash).  "to_json" turns it into a json string that non-ruby languages can read.  Bah.